# $.get() doesn't work with redirections

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing an extensions for google chrome that needs searching the contents of all urls in google search page.

For example after searching `jquery` in google search box I want to see `title tag` of all links in the result page. I'll get all links with `var links=$('a')` then I'm trying to use jquery `get()` function as the way bellow but it doesn't give me the right result:

```
$.get($('a')[i], function(data) {
    console.warn(data);
});
```

and the result is:

```
<script>window.googleJavaScriptRedirect=1</script><META       name="referrer" content="origin"><script>var m={navigateTo:function(b,a,d){if(b!=a&&b.google){if(b.google.r){b.google.r=0;b.location.href=d;a.location.replace("about:blank");}}else{a.location.replace(d);}}};m.navigateTo(window.parent,window,"https://www.facebook.com/r.php");</script><noscript><META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='https://www.facebook.com/r.php'"></noscript>
```

Comment: Obviously `$.get` cannot detect such type of redirect (initiated by Javascript code). You have to handle it manually: parse redirect url in the result and do appropriate request.

Comment: the problem is I'm not sure with count of redirections. maybe the link have redirection it self. Do you know any other command?

Comment: Count of redirections doesn't matter in this case. The problem is that you **cannot** handle such redirects automatically. There is no way at all except doing it **manually**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AJAX `$.get()` works with normal HTTP redirects.

The problem you have is that there is a JavaScript redirect on the page you are trying to load with `$.get()`. The code on the requested page will never run, so the redirect never happens.

Comment: As @hindmost said in the comments, it has to be done manually